# Static class in Blazor WASM

Tags: blazor-webassembly

We have a static class to store certain data at the application level. We set these property values when the user logs in. These values will be used wherever they are required.

In Blazor WASM, which approach is suitable for my case above? Appreciate if can provide some sample.

Thanks.

Comment: Is this data app wide? Or just specific to the user?

Comment: for both purpose. can be per user like (username, email) as well as per app like (campaign name)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Iam currently using a claim based approach, ( with azure B2C authentication ), where im storing the values i need into the claims:

```
string oid ="information to store";

(context.Principal.Identity as System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity).AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim("claim_name", oid));
```

set the info after the login:

```
 options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
        { OnTokenValidated = async context =>
                            {
                                  //SET THE INFO HERE
                            }
        }
```

Retrieve it by:

```
  public string get_info_in_claims(AuthenticationState authState)
        {
            string ret = "";
            foreach (var cla in authState.User.Claims)
            {
                if (cla.Type == "claim_name")
                {
                    ret = cla.Value;
                }
            }
            return ret;
        }
```